# i am runing into an OSError can you

Tags: python

I want to open a webpage with this code and it isn't working:

```
open ("https://app.plus500.com/trade/my-favourites")
```

The error is
OSError

Comment: `open` is for files not webpages

Comment: For opening webpages, use the `urllib` package ([see examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples)), or use the [`requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests) package.

Answer (score 1):

As @rdas said The python `open()` function used to open the system files.

If you wnat to open website you can use

```
import os
os.system("start \"\" https://app.plus500.com/trade/my-favourites")
```

or

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://app.plus500.com/trade/my-favourites")
```